# Parser for a new language plugin SonarQube

Tags: java, parsing, sonarqube, grammar

I finally finished to write the grammar of a new language inspiring myself from Python’s grammar here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python/blob/master/python-squid/src/main/java/org/sonar/python/api/PythonGrammar.java

So according to: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/new-languages/ , I should now write a parser. However, I really have no idea on how to do that, and when I go to Python’s parser (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python/blob/master/python-squid/src/main/java/org/sonar/python/parser/PythonParser.java), I don’t understand because it seems there is nothing to write.

Will it work if I use the one from the Python file ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Jérôme, It would be awesome if you can show your progress for ex: a code block or attempts you have made to solve this problem. that way others would understand your problem and will be able to help you faster. your question is too broad to answer here.

Comment: Hi, the thing is that I don't know how to test the parser either so I didn't try anything. I can show you the grammar part but it looks like the one from Python (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223868/matlab-grammar-to-enhance). Actually, I just need some help to get started on the parser writting.

Comment: Hi, I have used Slang https://github.com/SonarSource/slang/ project to rewrite jproperties plugin. Jproperties have wery simple gramar but I think you can get the base idea from this https://github.com/pepaproch/slang-jproperties/tree/master/sonar-properties-plugin/src/main/java/org/pepaproch/properties/parser/sslr.